# Configuration Backup in JUNOS using TFTP

Tags: configuration, tftp, juniper, junos-automation

Is there any way to auto backup in Junos using TFTP like Cisco..
I can't find any specific documentation like this..
I have already did it in CISCO XR router by using those command:

```
(config)#configuration commit auto-save filename tftp://x.x.x.x/x/x
(config)#tftp client source-interface Te0/x/x/x
```

Now I need to do it in JUNOS

Answer (score -1):

Please look for the solutions provided in the below links.

https://forums.juniper.net/t5/SRX-Services-Gateway/Weekly-Schedule-configuration-backup-auto/td-p/316188

https://www.itechlounge.net/2014/10/junos-how-to-configure-automated-configuration-backup/